# Why is this component not re-rendering

Tags: svelte, svelte-component

Why does the `Step` component not re-render when it's props (`aStep`) change?

```
//Game.svelte
import  Step  from './Step.svelte';

var states = [
    { name: "Red",     next: 1,  buttonText: "Goto2"},
    { name: "Yellow",  next: 2,  buttonText: "Goto3" },
    { name: "Green",   next: 3,  buttonText: "Goto4"},
    { name: "Blue",    next: 0,  buttonText: "Goto1"},
];

  
let curState =  states[0]
var stepNumber = 1;
var theStep = undefined;

function nextStep() {
        makeStep(curState, stepNumber);
        stepNumber++;  
    curState=states[curState.next];

        console.log(theStep)
}

function makeStep(state, stepNumber) {
    theStep = {
        title: "Step:" + stepNumber + " " +state.name,
        buttonText: state.buttonText,
        buttonAction: nextStep
    }
}
</script>

<input id="startBtn" name="Submit" type="submit" value="Start" on:click={nextStep}/>

{#if theStep}
    <Step aStep = {theStep}/>
{/if}
```

The `Step` component:

```
<script>
    export let aStep;

    let {title, buttonText, buttonAction} = aStep

</script>

<div>
    <p class = "title">{title}</p>
    <div class ="stepBody">
        <button on:click={buttonAction}>{buttonText}</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can see with the `console.log` that `theStep` is changeing with every button press, yet the `Step` component remains unchanged.

There is a Svelte REPL [here](https://svelte.dev/repl/5cabcdfd133c41099d934cf0c09a8568?version=3.46.2)

Comment: Make the let reactive in the Step component: 
$: {title, buttonText, buttonAction} = aStep;
By replacing the let with $: ...

Comment: @voscausa I tried that, that is giving me an error in the REPL tried with and without variations of let/var/const

Comment: You do not need the let / var or const. $: {title, buttonText, buttonAction} = aStep; will do

Comment: @voscausa tried that also

Comment: Try wrapping everything in parenthesis `$: ({title, buttonText, buttonAction} = aStep)`

Comment: Yes sorry. Corrl is right.

Comment: Parens! That's the trick! Thanks so much, spent 2hours on that stupid thing. THX @Corrl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the destructuring inside `Step.svelte` reactive, change the line to

```
 $: ({title, buttonText, buttonAction} = aStep)
```

or alternatively and maybe even better to read, spread the props on the object and export the keys you want to use directly

[App.svelte]

```
{#if theStep}
    <Step {...theStep}/>
{/if}
```

[Step.svelte]

```
<script>
    export let title, buttonText, buttonAction
</script>
```